# Deploy Stage failed with cf login: incorrect usage

Tags: authentication, deployment, ibm-cloud

I'm going through Lab 2 of the IBM Cloud Essentials class (CL0101EN), and am trying to deploy the sample app nodejs-cloudant. For the Delivery Pipeline I had to create an API key, which I did by clicking the "Create" button, then I clicked "Deploy". Here the Deploy stage failed with the following error:

Preparing to start the job...
Preparing the build artifacts...
cf login -a "https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net" -u apikey -p "****" -o "Bolik Corp." -s "dev" 
Incorrect Usage: expected argument for flag `-p', but got option`****'

NAME:
   login - Log user in

USAGE:
   cf login [-a API_URL] [-u USERNAME] [-p PASSWORD] [-o ORG] [-s SPACE] [--sso | --sso-passcode PASSCODE]

WARNING:
   Providing your password as a command line option is highly discouraged
   Your password may be visible to others and may be recorded in your shell history

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's odd to me that it would have you create an API key but then supply username and password parameters. Typically you'd use the following command and flag to login with an API Key:

```
ibmcloud login --apikey <the api key>
```

That's the point of the API key - to act as your identity so you don't share or rely on a username and password.

In your Toolchain, edit the Deploy stage by clicking the icon that looks like a gear (Configure Stage). Then select the failing job. In the Deploy job's script, is it doing an explicit login command? The toolchain should handle that automatically and there's no need to execute a login command yourself. It may be as simple as removing any `login` command in the deployment script.

Can you also link to or provide instructions on how you created the toolchain? I'm interested in what it provides as the deployment script.

UPDATE:

I think I see what's happening. Your `cf login` is being automatically run from the Cloud Foundry Deployer type. That explains where the command comes from. Toolchains have recently had the statement, "WARNING: Deploying to Cloud Foundry without specifying an API KEY is DEPRECATED. Press the [CONFIGURE] button above to include an API KEY for this job."

What I would do is double-check your API Key. Specifically, the 'API key' textbox should list the *name* of the key, for example, 'my-toolchain-key'. If it's something else or blank, something is wrong. Create a new API Key using the `ibmcloud iam api-key-create <api-key-name>` command. Then update the textfield. For me, there was an issue when the API Key was created using using the 'Deploy to IBM Cloud' toolchain examples. It was only after I manually edited the toolchain was the issue solved. I've made the toolchain developers aware of the issue to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just redid the whole lab, again created an API key which the Deploy stage was automatically configured with, and now it worked fine. Interestingly, in the log the login command looks exactly as in my question above, yet this time it succeeded:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I just redid the whole lab, again created an API key which the Deploy stage was automatically configured with, and now it worked fine. Interestingly, in the log the login command looks exactly as in my question above, yet this time it succeeded:

cf login -a "https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net" -u apikey -p "****" -o "Bolik Corp." -s "dev" 
API endpoint: https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net
Authenticating...
OK

I checked the configuration of the Deploy state in my failed delivery pipeline, I used an API key in the exact same way. So it looks like I ran into some internal flaw which corrected itself (or was corrected) in the meantime.